# dxf-Export is not readable in BricsCad

Tags: qgis, export, dxf

With the QGIS 2.8 dxf-Export it is not possible to open these files in BricsCad (a CAD-Programm which is very similar to AutoCad).

the dxf-Export from GIS 2.8 and import in BricsCad looks like!(not valid object/owner)[image]

The dxf-Export from GIS 2.8 and import in BricsCad looks like[image]

BKS/Welt regconize the the CRS

Are there any suggestions?

---

the dxf-Export from GIS 2.8 and import in BricsCad looks like!(not valid object/owner)[image]

the dxf-Export from GIS 2.8 and import in BricsCad looks like[image]

BKS/Welt regconize the the CRS

Comment: Any errors when you try to open the file?

Comment: Does this work successfully for you in other CAD software (e.g. AutoCAD)?

Comment: I can not test in AC but BricsCad is very similar to AC